# How to make my webSite indexed by Google Search

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, sitemap, google-index

I have been trying to make my website indexed by google. I tried every solution on the internet, and passed more than 1 week and Google haven't indexed it yet. I don't know what I can do. What I did:

1 Created sitemap.xml
2 Created robots.txt
3 Associate my website on my google account (google search console)
4 Google has recognized that the site is mine.
5 I submit sitemap.xml to google

I have been waiting for more than 1 week, and even writing full url at google my website isn't there. I have no ideias why can I solve this anymore. Here is my relevant source codes

Site: [www.gorilafreela.com.br](http://www.gorilafreela.com.br)

Searching it on google: https://www.google.com/search?q=www.gorilafreela.com.br&rlz=1C1CHBD_pt-BRBR927BR927&sxsrf=APq-WBviL03-MZ2rg3Nq88fLtrTqZHsVIw%3A1644005097965&ei=6Yb9YYe1Oque5OUPwImO2Ao&ved=0ahUKEwjHzf2e7Ob1AhUrD7kGHcCEA6sQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=www.gorilafreela.com.br&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgjELADECc6BwgjEOoCECc6BAgjECc6BAgAEEM6CAgAEIAEELEDOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToLCC4QgAQQsQMQgwE6CAguEIAEELEDOg4ILhCABBCxAxDHARDRAzoLCC4QgAQQxwEQ0QM6BQgAEIAEOggIABCxAxCDAToHCAAQsQMQQzoHCCMQsAIQJzoECAAQDToGCAAQDRAeOggIABANEAoQHjoECC4QDUoECEEYAUoECEYYAFDGDli_KmDRMGgCcAB4AIABlAGIAbIVkgEEMC4yM5gBAKABAbABCsgBAsABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

   <url>

      <loc>https://www.gorilafreela.com.br/</loc>

      <lastmod>2022-01-25</lastmod>

      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>

      <priority>0.8</priority>

   </url>
   <url>

      <loc>https://gorilafreela.com.br/projeto/criar</loc>

      <lastmod>2022-01-25</lastmod>

      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>

      <priority>0.6</priority>

   </url>

</urlset>
```

```
Sitemap: https://gorilafreela.com.br/sitemap.xml

User-agent: *
Allow: /
Allow: /projeto/criar
```

[image: As you can see Google notified the sitemap.xml has already been processed, but why it isn't at google search?]

Comment: None of the things you have done influence whether or not Google indexes a site.  Sitemaps, robots.txt, and search console don't make Google index anything.  The only things that really help are: 1. Waiting (up to a year) and 2. Getting external links from other sites

Comment: Post on some of these big websites, you'll get indexed in 24 hours: https://www.wix.com/blog/2016/12/free-places-to-promote-your-website/

Comment: Yes I agree you will want to work on your inbound links next.